# Prepend data to stream in C#

Tags: c#, stream, audio, xna

I'm working on an XNA project that loads several resources that are packed into a single file. XNA can take a WAV file stream and turn that into a SoundEffect (seen below in "case ".wav"").

Since WAV files are large, I want to enable MP3 audio as one of the resources, so I found [MP3Sharp](https://github.com/ZaneDubya/MP3Sharp), a cross-platform library that converts mp3 file data into PCM data.(just the wavform data, no headers.) Unfortunately, the method I have to use to integrate this in, "**SoundEffect.FromStream(Stream stream)**", is expecting **both** the WAV file **headers** and the **PCM data** (waveform) To do this, I am using several MemoryStreams and my instinct tells me that it is horribly inefficient.(noticeably too)  Below you will find the code, the **important part being the "case ".mp3":"** portion. **How can I do this better?**

**tl;dr: Prepend/combine streams in C#, how?** (also note that nChannels and nSamplesPerSec need to be discovered from decoding the mp3 file)

I am worried that I am taking the wrong approach to reading from the stream and

```
byte[] data = reader.ReadBytes(reader.ReadInt32());
files[path] = data;
string extension = Path.GetExtension(path);
switch (extension)
{
    case ".png":
        string texturePath = Path.ChangeExtension(path, null);
        using (MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            textures[texturePath] = Texture2D.FromStream(Main.instance.GraphicsDevice, buffer);
        }
        break;
    case ".wav":
        string soundPath = Path.ChangeExtension(path, null);
        using (MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            sounds[soundPath] = SoundEffect.FromStream(buffer);
        }
        break;
    case ".mp3":
        // TODO, better way to do this?
        string mp3Path = Path.ChangeExtension(path, null);
        MemoryStream wavData = new MemoryStream();
        MemoryStream wavFile = new MemoryStream();
        ushort wFormatTag = 1;
        ushort nChannels;
        uint nSamplesPerSec;
        uint nAvgBytesPerSec;
        ushort nBlockAlign;
        ushort wBitsPerSample = 16;
        using (MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            using (MP3Sharp.MP3Stream s = new MP3Sharp.MP3Stream(buffer))
            {
                s.CopyTo(wavData);
                nChannels = (ushort)s.ChannelCount;
                nSamplesPerSec = (uint)s.Frequency;
            }
        }
        nBlockAlign = (ushort)(nChannels * (wBitsPerSample / 8));
        nAvgBytesPerSec = (uint)(nSamplesPerSec * nChannels * (wBitsPerSample / 8));
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(wavFile))
        {
            bw.Write("RIFF".ToCharArray());
            bw.Write((UInt32)(wavData.Length + 36));
            bw.Write("WAVE".ToCharArray());
            bw.Write("fmt ".ToCharArray());
            bw.Write(16);
            bw.Write(wFormatTag);
            bw.Write(nChannels);
            bw.Write(nSamplesPerSec);
            bw.Write(nAvgBytesPerSec);
            bw.Write(nBlockAlign);
            bw.Write(wBitsPerSample);
            bw.Write("data".ToCharArray());
            bw.Write((UInt32)(wavData.Length));
            bw.Write(wavData.ToArray());
        }
        using (MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream(wavFile.ToArray()))
        {
            sounds[mp3Path] = SoundEffect.FromStream(buffer);
        }
        break;
    }
```

[The full method is available on GitHub.](https://github.com/bluemagic123/tModLoader/blob/master/patches/tModLoader/Terraria.ModLoader/ModLoader.cs#L302)

Comment: Fixed, I've added a link to the full method. I didn't want people getting distracted so I tried to abide by the rules but also limit the code to facilitate focus.

Comment: Maybe https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio/ would be a better choice for converting mp3 to wav.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Heslacher, should be fairly easy to do with [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio).

```
var output = new MemoryStream();
using (var reader = new Mp3FileReader(mp3File))
using (var writer = new WaveFileWriter(output, reader.WaveFormat))
{
    //read from reader, write to writer, like you would do with regular streams
    //header is appended automatically to output stream in WaveFileWriter constructor
}
```

You should also consider encapsulating your resource loading logic to separate class (or classes: one class per resource type). Handling textures and sound in single method looks messy. [Single resposibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

**EDIT:** If you have to stick to the library of your choosing, then you should just use single output stream.

```
var output = new MemoryStream();
using (var input = new MP3Sharp.MP3Stream(yourMp3FileStream))
using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(output, Encoding.UTF8, true))
{
    var headerSize = 44; //or w/e it is for RIFF, I might have forgotten
    output.Position = headerSize;
    input.CopyTo(output);
    output.Position = 0;
    //wtite your header
    writer.Write("RIFF".ToCharArray());
    ...
}
```

Also notice, that you can stack `using`s on top of each other without adding extra braces.

Comment: NAudio, from what I can gather, isn't cross-platform. (I didn't mention cross platform because I had already chosen a library, and I spend a long time searching for something suitable) I'm mostly worried about the flow here, since it seems convoluted, but I can't see how to streamline it.

Comment: @JavidPack I edited my answer.